# SWIFT 4 Present viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I am trying to building a app using the master details template.
in the Master view controller I added a button called Catalogue : this button showing a tabbar controller called Catalogue.

[image]

I don't use Segue to show the catalogue, I use the code below to show the tab controller

From Master form I called the Tabbar controller :

```
@IBAction func Btn_Catalogue(_ sender: Any) {
   let AddCatalogueVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CatalogueVC") as! CatalogueVC
   present(AddCatalogueVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

From CategorieVC I use the code below to show

```
@IBAction func Btn_AddCategorie(_ sender: Any) {
    self.Mode = "New"
    let AddCategorieViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCategorieVC") as! AddCategorieVC
    present(AddCategorieViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I dismiss the AddCategorieVC using the code below

```
  @IBAction func Btn_Save(_ sender: Any) 
    {
        if self.Txt_CategorieName.text  != ""{
            self.Mysave = true
            self.MyCategorieName = self.Txt_CategorieName.text!
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
        }
```

I have unwind SEGUE from Save button to a function in categorieVC

```
 @IBAction func FctSaveCategories(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
  let sendervc = sender.source as! AddCategorieVC
        if self.Mode == "New" && sendervc.Mysave == true  { // Mode insert



            let MyCategories = TblCategorie(context: Mycontext)
            MyCategories.categorie_Name = sendervc.MyCategorieName
             do {
              try Mycontext.save()
    } catch {
        debugPrint ("there is an error  \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when I hit the save button in categorieVC the catalogueVC is also dismissing at the same time returning me to the master control.

I am almost sure that the problem came from the Unwind segue but I don't know why.

**Update**: I activate the Cancel button in AddCategorieVC with the code below

```
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and when I clicked on it only the AddCategorieVC is being dismissed and I go back to CatalogueVC. The difference between the save button and the Cancel Button is only the UNWIND segue on the Save Button.

And when I add UnWIND segue to the cancel Button (just to test the behavior) it took me back to the master form instead CatalogueVC.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yesss I found it

It look like that unwind segue automaticly handled dismiss contrôle

So all I need to do is remove the dismiss code from the save button this way the unwind segue will took me back to catalogueVC.

.

Comment: Congratulations :) please mark your answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark so the question doesn't show up as unanswered. Keeping SO clean!